# Android Handler NullPointerException

Tags: android-listview, nullpointerexception, handler, android

1. The `Activity` creates a new `Thread`.
2. The `run()` method gets an object (`vector`) via input stream.
3. Now I want to display the contents of this `Vector` on a `ListView` called `direc`.
4. That's all...but its not working and throws an `Exception`.

The code:

```
public class FileExplorerActivity extends Activity implements Runnable
{
    public static final String TAG="ricky";
    Vector<String> dirs = new Vector<String>();
    ListView direc;
    static ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fileexplorer);
        direc = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.directoriesss);
        handler = new Handler();
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public FileExplorerActivity() 
    {

    }

    public void run()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "FileExplorer: Thread started");
        try
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "FileExplorer: reading data");
            dirs = (Vector<String>) ConnectionThread.din.readObject();
            Log.d(TAG, "FileExplorer: read data");
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                                     android.R.layout.activity_list_item,
                                     android.R.id.text2 , dirs);            
            Log.d(TAG, "FileExplorer: ArrayAdapter created");

            handler.post( new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "FileExplorer: In handler Thread");
                    direc.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    Log.d(TAG, "FileExplorer: Updated UI");
                }
            });

            Log.d(TAG, "FileExplorer: Directory set");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "FileExplorerActivity: Exception:"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what Logcat has to say:

```
> 1. 05-24 20:14:46.601  7759  7834 D ricky   : FileExplorer: Thread started
> 2. 05-24 20:14:46.601  7759  7834 D ricky   : FileExplorer: reading data
> 3. 05-24 20:14:46.648  7759  7834 D ricky   : FileExplorer: read data
> 4. 05-24 20:14:46.648  7759  7834 D ricky   : FileExplorer: ArrayAdapter created
> 5. 05-24 20:14:46.648  7759  7834 D ricky   : FileExplorer: Directory set
> 6. 05-24 20:14:46.656  7759  7759 D ricky   : FileExplorer: In handler Thread
> 7. 05-24 20:14:46.656  7759  7759 D ricky   : FileExplorer: Updated UI
> 8. 05-24 20:14:46.664  7759  7759 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
> 9. 05-24 20:14:46.664  7759  7759 W dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught 10. exception (group=0x4001e560)
> 11. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 12. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 13. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:353)
> 14. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
> 15. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1456)
> 16. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java :1291)
> 17. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1202)
> 18. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8355)
> 19. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java :3279)
> 20. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
> 21. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.ja va:701)
> 22. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:311)
> 23. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8355)
> 24. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java :3279)
> 25. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
> 26. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8355)
> 27. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java :531)
> 28. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
> 29. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8355)
> 30. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java :3279)
> 31. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
> 32. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8355)
> 33. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:882)
> 34. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1917)
> 35. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 36. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
> 37. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3859)
> 38. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 39. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
> 40. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
> 41. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
> 42. 05-24 20:14:46.687  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: no dirs is not null...have tested it against if(dirs ==null) and it isn't...also dirs has all the rows...i have printed it it actual program.

Comment: R.layout.fileexplorer contains R.id.directoriesss ?

Comment: yes it does...out of frustration ;)

Comment: try moving the creation of ArrayAdapter inside the Handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the line at which the `NullPointerException` occurs:

`android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:353)`

---

This is because`android.R.layout.activity_list_item` does not contain `android.R.id.text2`.

You can use `android.R.id.text1` instead or replace the row layout with `simple_list_item_2`.

I would suggest creating your own row layout to avoid these situations in the first place.

Comment: yes that Exception went away after using android.R.id.text1 insted of text2...thanks a lot Che...but why isn't the Listview direc getting updated with the rows contained in Vector dirs...it has rows.

Comment: Not sure, as David mentioned, you may have to create this on the UI thread. Also, your static reference `arrayAdapter` will cause a memory leak as it holds a reference to the activity. Make `arrayAdapter` a non-static reference (as with all objects that hold a reference to a `Context`).

Answer (score 0):

Move this

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item,
        android.R.id.text2 , dirs);
```

inside your run() method so that it runs on the UI thread. You shouldn't create an ArrayAdapter outside of the UI thread.

Comment: sir actually    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text2 , dirs);
 this was the source of exception android.R.id.text1 instedof text2 solved it...

Comment: OK, that's good. I still would create the ArrayAdapter on the UI thread though. Glad you were able to get a solution to your problem.

Comment: it worked when I moved the creation of ArrayAdapter inside of Handler...thanks a lot...actually there was a problem in Layout file, I had to specify android:orientation="vertical" to get the proper layout...but one thing if ArrayAdapter was declared in the main Activity class as earlier wasn't it in the GUI workspace already ???

Comment: No. In your original code (posted above), you created the ArrayAdapter inside the `run()` method. That method is called on the new Thread that you created inside your `onCreate()` method. Even though the variable `arrayAdapter` is **declared** in the main Activity, the actual object was being created in another Thread (not the main UI thread). The problem is that the Android UI framework is not thread-safe and it is designed to be used only from a single thread.

Comment: ok yes...got it...how do I mark both the answers right ??? yours as well as Che's...I cannot vote up.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. But that's all right. Glad to be of some help anyway. When you get some more reputation you can come back and vote up my answer :-D